# touch action in scroll view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

My project based on touch event in scrollview. im using the following code but it shows an error. gesture undeclared. how to declare gesture please tell me,

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapGestureCaptured:)];
[scrollView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];  


- (void)singleTapGestureCaptured:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)touch
  { 
    CGPoint touchPoint=[gesture locationInView:scrollView];
  }
```

Comment: what is `gesture` here in `[gesture locationInView:scrollView];` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry I didn't look at your code carefully

```
CGPoint touchPoint=[touch locationInView:scrollView];
```

use this.

You dont have any variable named gesture.

Comment: sorry still gesture undeclared

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare an UITouch object for that.

```
UITouch *gesture;
```

Beacause you can pass the locationInView method only to UITouch class objects.Otherwise it will throw an error.